# Integrating JPreloader in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, splash-screen, jpreloader

I have successfully implemented the [Jpreloader](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2T3ilwq97Y4ODk2X2wzeTZWZUU/edit?usp=sharing) functionality on my local machine with some files . I am new to wordpress developing . Its not that I am lazy , but I dont understand the wordpress architecture . The code that I have implemented is as follows :

the html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE  HTML>
<html>
    <head>


        <title> JPreLoader Tutorial </title>

    <!-- STEP 1 linking jQuery and JPreloader Library -->

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 


        <script type="text/javascript" src="jpreloader.js"></script>

    <!-- STEP 1 ends  -- >

        <!-- STEP 3 : Adding Style -->

        <style type="text/css">     


            body {
                display: none;
            }



            .decorate {
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: blac;
            }

            #jpreOverlay, #qLoverlay
            {
            background-color: #FFF;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 11
            }
            #jpreSlide {
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: 700;
            color: #FFF;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%
            }
            #jpreLoader, #qLloader {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: url(speight.png) 0 100% no-repeat;
            position: fixed;
            top: 43%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -50px
            }
            #jpreBar, #qLbar {
            width: 100px;
            height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            background: url(speight.png) -100px 100% no-repeat
            }
            #jprePercentage, #qLpercentage {
            color: #888;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            height: 30px;
            width: 100px;
            bottom: -30px
            }
        </style>        
          <!-- STEP 3 Ends -->
    </head>
    <body>      
        <center>        

        <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/181548_153793501342544_153515891370305_259700_7241508_n.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/196528_158118380910056_153515891370305_283882_234528_n.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/196556_159931940728700_153515891370305_293999_6261181_n.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/205687_165495210172373_153515891370305_326385_1869822_n.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/205600_167760236612537_153515891370305_338177_2160812_n.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/248150_174306909291203_153515891370305_374445_3774819_n.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/228343_171546129567281_153515891370305_358267_5126730_n.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/249232_174478049274089_153515891370305_375652_2662480_n.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/268903_186646411390586_153515891370305_435046_34596_n.jpg" /></li>

        </center>


            <!-- STEP 2 -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('body').jpreLoader({loaderVPos: '40%'});
            }); 

            <!-- STEP 2 Ends -->

            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**
**

The splash image is :

### [image]

**

### The output is as :

**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really say what the problem was. It is the fact that the black square is a rectangle instead?

Do you have this page uploaded somewhere that I can see it?

At first glance, I'm guessing the reason its a rectangle is because of this:

```
height: 30px;
width: 100px;
```

Also, the center tag is deprecated, you shouldn't use it. try using this instead:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Hope this helps, if not, please provide more information.

Comment: You can find the files herehttps://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2T3ilwq97Y4ODk2X2wzeTZWZUU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking to integrate this into WordPress you should start with learning how to correctly include jQuery CDN and the jPreloader script into WordPress correctly.

You'll want to make sure that the jPreloader is dependent on jQuery and that it is correctly enqueued. Here is a good link to get started [Registering Scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)

Here is an example code of me loading jPreloader in WordPress. You'll want to place this into your functions.php file.

```
wp_register_script('jPreloader', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/plugins/jpreloader.min.js', 'jquery', null, false);
wp_register_script('mainJS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', 'jquery', null, true);

wp_enqueue_script('jPreloader');
wp_enqueue_script('mainJS');
```

Once you've got the jPreloader script loaded and ready and your .js file ready (I named mine main.js) you want to include this in your .js file

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 jQuery('body').jpreLoader();
 });
```

Then you can start playing with the css from there. I used Google Chrome Dev Tools to pause it when I needed to edit the CSS.

A good live example of a working jPreloader with a sprite is [Adham Dannaway's Portfolio Website](http://www.adhamdannaway.com/). You can look through his CSS source and how he included the sprite to get a good starting point for getting jPreloader to look good.

Comment: Thank you , I will try it  ! Actually before posting this question , I referred to adham's website , and was inspired by that !